# Transfer data from a second xml file to the first, or merge two Excel sheets into one, based on column criteria

Tags: xml, excel

I have a sheet (or XML file) named 1, which in column A, has First Names, and Column B, has Last names. Column E has emails.

In another sheet, or XML file, named 2, I have column C which has First Names, Column D, has Last names, and column Y, which has emails, and column Z, which has phone numbers.

I need to add data to the first sheet, based on the match of column A and B, from the first sheet, with columns C and D, in the second sheet.

For each row in the first sheet, that column A equals a row in sheet 2, column C AND the same row in sheet a column B must equal again the same row in sheet b in column D, I need to add to the email column (E), the value of column Y, and if it already has an email there, split them with a | character. Also, add in column E, the value of column z, only if it has a value, and it is not blank.
I have tried with Excel index and match functions, and array formulas, but I would like feedback, on how I could achieve this, with xml files.

XML file 1

```
<MEMBERID="54">
            <FIRSTNAME>JOHAN</FIRSTNAME>
            <LASTNAME>DOE</LASTNAME>
            <EMAIL>eye@mail.com</EMAIL>
            <OTHERDATA>...</OTHERDATA>
            <OTHERDATA2>7036339</OTHERDATA2>
            ...
                    </MEMBERID>
```

XML file 2

```
<MEMBERID="1254">
            <FIRSTNAME>JOHAN</FIRSTNAME>
            <LASTNAME>DOE</LASTNAME>
            <EMAIL>another@email.com</EMAIL>
            <ADDRESS>...</ADDRESS>
            <PHONE>54545545</PHONE>
            <PONUMBER>7036339</PONUMBER>
            ...
                    </MEMBERID>
```

RESULT XML:

```
<MEMBERID="54">
            '<FIRSTNAME>JOHAN</FIRSTNAME>'
            <LASTNAME>DOE</LASTNAME>
            <EMAIL>7036339|another@email.com||eye@mail.com</EMAIL>
            <OTHERDATA>...</OTHERDATA>
            <OTHERDATA2>7036339</OTHERDATA2>
            ...
                    </MEMBERID>
``
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What technology do you intend to use? What is your desired output? Can you give an example?

Comment: i have tried with excel index and match functions, and array formuls, but i would like feedback, on how i could achieve this, with xml files.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why is *PONumber* concatenated in the resulting email node? And can there be more than one repeating names in second xml (i.e., multiple *Johan Doe*)?

Comment: no, only one Johan Doe, in the first XML, matches only one Johan Doe in the second

Comment: To clarify, Johan Doe in the first xml, may or may not exist, only once in the second xml

Comment: And my first question about PONumber? By the way, looking closer this is NOT a well-formed XML as the `<MEMBERID="54">` is not valid. No node name can be assigned an attribute value. Check how these XMLs are being produced.